# How should I create this database structure, think I am getting a fantrap

Tags: database, nhibernate

I have a RESTful server which I use as a server for mobile games, I am now trying to create a database (Using NHibernate) but I am not certain how to do this certain thing properly in a database

In the database there are users, each user can participate in many games, game is a superclass which QDGame inherits (that class also has children that inherits but thats not important here) so one player can be part of 10 QDGame's

My dillemma is that X number of players can be part of one Game, so should I have a list down in Game of type List? I would think thats wrong, as each player would have many games and each game would have many players (Fantrap?)

So how should I have the link between many games shared between many users?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question properly, you are looking for a many-to-many relationship here

```
Users [UserId, ....]
Games [GameId, ...]
GameUsers[GameUserId, GameId, UserId, ...]
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a many-to-many? This is the correct approach to your problem.

Comment: Fan trap as mentioned is only relevant from a transactional perspective w.r.t your object model, i.e. in context of a game it would be  GameUsers, while for Users it would be UserGames, depending how your processes are defined this would be the best way to approach, although would like to see if there is alternative

Comment: I will create a junction like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table so I create a UserGame which has a Id, Game and User

So each game gets x number of UserGame where x is the number of players in the game